# Can't close dropdown inside a div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu, getuikit

This is my situation;
I've got a input search. When i click in it, a new div appears under this input. Inside this div (the div it works like a dropdown basically), there's a dropdown button (i'm using uikit as css framework and Angularjs). I created a directive that when a user click inside this div the div stays open, but when a user click outside it, it closes. It's working but i've got a problem right now. Assuming i click the dropdown button, it will open it. What i would is that if i click outside this button, even if i click inside the div, it will close the dropdown. Actually doesn't work. It close everything only if i click outide the "big" div. I know it's difficult to explain but i'm trying to do my best. By the way here's a jsfiddle i've created with the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/120/
I post some code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">      
   <form class="uk-form uk-margin-large">
       <input autocomplete="off"
               data-ng-click="openSearch();"
               style="padding-left: 35px!important;"
               hide-search="hideSearchContainer()"
               data-ng-model="searchText" class="uk-width-1-1" type="search"
               placeholder="Hello">
        <div hide-search="hideSearchContainer()" data-ng-class="{'search-input':userSearch,
                     'search-input-closed':!userSearch}"
                     class="search-input-closed">
          <div class="uk-width-1-3 center-pane">

                            <div class="uk-button-dropdown" title="Click here" data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}">
                                <button type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-primary qt-button-dropdown-material">
                                    <span class="qt-dropdown-text-material">Types</span>
                                </button>

                                <div class="uk-dropdown qt-dropdown uk-dropdown-scrollable" style="">
                                    <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown" id="kb_menu">
                                         <li key-navigation ng-repeat="item in items">
                            <a href="">{{item}}</a>
                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>               

    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's the controller in Angularjs with the directive

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.items=['menu item 1','menu item 2'];
    $scope.openSearch = function(){
            $scope.userSearch = true;
        };

  $scope.hideSearchContainer = function(){
    $scope.userSearch = false;
  };
    $scope.itemClicked = function(item, event, index){

    }

    $(document).on('click', '.uk-dropdown', function() {
        $(this).parents('[data-uk-dropdown]:first').removeClass('uk-open');
    });
});

myApp.directive('hideSearch', function($document){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $document.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(attr.hideSearch);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks. I am available to provide any other information

Comment: Why not just toggle the dropdown? So always you click, you reverse if its seen or not. http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/122/ But, for a body-click event, you need to give a div the full height to be clickable.

Comment: hmm i can't understand if you have changed something in your jsfiddle compared to mine

Comment: Sorry, here the new link: http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/123/ Still there is a problem. Somehow your $document.bind(click) is getting triggered twice. Otherwise it would work.

Comment: Also docs says - Add class .uk-dropdown-close to dropdown container or to item to hide dropdown when user click on item. Tried, but not working :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was e.stopPropagation() in directive.
That was preventing all click events of its' child.
so I've removed it and add some condition on document.bind and seems working.

Here's script

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.items=['menu item 1','menu item 2'];
    $scope.openSearch = function(){
            $scope.userSearch = true;
        };

  $scope.hideSearchContainer = function(){
    $scope.userSearch = false;
  };
    $scope.itemClicked = function(item, event, index){

    }
    $(document).on('click', '.uk-dropdown', function() {
        $(this).parents('[data-uk-dropdown]:first').removeClass('uk-open');
    });

});

myApp.directive('hideSearch', function($document){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                //e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $document.bind('click', function(e) {
                if(e.target.className == "uk-notouch")
                   scope.$apply(attr.hideSearch);
            });

        }
    }
});
```